# Particionando un string con Split

Tags: java

estoy intentando particionar un string con split, pero no obtengo el resultado deseado

```
String cadena = "r1";
 String []posString = cadena.split("r");
 System.out.println(posString[0]); // <--Devuelve "" y no "1"
```

Si hago `split("1")` si devuelve "r". ¿Qué puede ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), el método deja un elemento vacío para la ocurrencia de la expresión usada como separador

De la documentación:

> The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results
>   with these expressions:
>
> ```
> Regex     Result
> :     { "boo", "and", "foo" }
> o     { "b", "", ":and:f" }
> ```

Este comportamiento seguro está relacionado con el que la expresión usada para separar el String, es usada como una expresión regular.

Siguiendo la documentación, esta versión equivale a usar la definición del método que tiene [límite de ocurrencias](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)),

```
split(String regex, int limit)
```

con un valor límite de cero.

En la definición de ésta versión, se ve más claro por qué queda uno vacío en tu array. Detallan que:

> The array returned by this method contains each substring of this
>   string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given
>   expression or is terminated by the end of the string. The substrings
>   in the array are in the order in which they occur in this string. If
>   the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting
>   array has just one element, namely this string.

Es decir que este split retorna un elemento de array por cada substring que **termina** con la expresión dada (o con el final del String original). Entonces, tu primer elemento vacío es el conjunto de caracteres antes de la `r` que terminan con `r`.

Para el ejemplo del método anterior, sale un elemento vacío entre `b` y `:and:f` porque hay un espacio vacío entre las dos `o` que contiene... exacto, un conjunto vacío de caracteres.

`b o o
    ^`

Más claro, ¿verdad? Siempre hay que ir a la documentación, que ahí se encuentran estos detalles. :)

PD. Me sorprendió que `String []posString = cadena.split("r");` compilara y funcionara. Aprendí / recordé algo hoy.

Comment: Siguiendo tu respuesta, lo único que he tenido que hacer es acceder a la posición 1 del array. No obstante sigo sin entender porque deja un espacio con la 'o' y con ':' no

Comment: @UsuarioRandom Mira la edición de la respuesta